# How can I pass Twig sub parameter?

Tags: perl, twig

Help I can't pass my hash key to twig subroutine.

here:

```
foreach my $word (sort { $keywords{$a} <=> $keywords{$b} } keys (%keywords)) {
my $t = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots   => { 'Id' => \&insert($keywords{$word}) } );

    $t->parse($docsums);

    sub insert 
    { 
        my($t, $id, $k)= @_;

        my $p =  $id->text;      

        my $query    = "insert into pres (id, wid, p) values(DEFAULT, '$k', '$p')";
        my $sql      = $connect->prepare($query);
        $sql->execute( );   

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to curry `insert` but Perl doesn't directly support that. Instead, you can use an anonymous sub to build the proper argument list for `insert`:

```
'Id' => sub { insert($_[0], $_[1], $keywords{$word}) }
```

Comment: usually I write this using @_: sub { insert( @_, $keywords{$word}); }

Comment: @mirod: That'll work too but I like to be explicit to make it easier on myself a couple weeks later; a 2 element slice of `@_` would also work. OTOH, if `$keywords{$word}` went first I'd say `sub { insert($keywords{$word}, @_) }`.